# Multi layouts with Ionic and Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, layout

I'm trying to manage differents layouts in Ionic/Vue app. I want to have a default layout, and unlogged layout and a inGameLayout instead of importing differents components on each view.

Here is one of my layout:

```
<template>
    <ion-page>
        <ion-header>
            <ion-toolbar>
                <ion-title>Default-layout: {{ title }}</ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content>
            <slot />
        </ion-content>
    </ion-page>
</template>
  
<script lang="ts">
import { IonPage, IonToolbar, IonHeader, IonTitle, IonContent } from '@ionic/vue';
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'DefaultLayout',
    components: {
        IonPage,
        IonHeader,
        IonToolbar,
        IonTitle,
        IonContent
    },
    data() {
        return {
            title: this.$route.meta.title
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

I indicate which layout should be used in my router :

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from '@ionic/vue-router';
import { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';
import store from '../store'

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: '/homepage',
    meta: { layout: "default", requiresAuth: true, title: "HomePage" },
    component: () => import('@/views/HomePage.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/homepage2',
    meta: { layout: "default", requiresAuth: true, title: "HomePage2" },
    component: () => import('@/views/HomePage2.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    meta: { layout: "unlogged", title: "Login" },
    component: () => import('@/views/LoginForm.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    meta: { layout: "unlogged", title: "Register" },
    component: () => import('@/views/RegisterForm.vue'),
  }
]


const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

In main.ts, i add my differents layouts:

```
...
/* Layouts */
import UnLoggedLayout from "./layouts/UnLoggedLayout.vue"
import InGameLayout from "./layouts/InGameLayout.vue"
import DefaultLayout from "./layouts/DefaultLayout.vue"

const app = createApp(App).use(store)
  .use(IonicVue)
  .use(router)
  .component('default-layout', DefaultLayout)
  .component('unlogged-layout', UnLoggedLayout)
  .component('ingame-layout', InGameLayout)

...
```

And i manage logic layout part in App.vue:

```
<template>
  <ion-app>
    <component :is="layout">
      <ion-router-outlet />
    </component>
  </ion-app>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { IonApp, IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/vue';

const defaultLayout = "default"

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    IonApp,
    IonRouterOutlet
  },
  computed: {
    layout() {
      return (this.$route.meta.layout || defaultLayout) + '-layout'
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

All seems ok when i navigate from a view with a layout to view with a different layout (forexample, from login to homepage)

But when i'm trying to navigate between different views with same layout, that doesn't work.
For example, when i'm trying to navigate from homepage to homepage2, component Homepage2 is added to current page that is not resfreshed. So i have a page with both components, HomePage and HomePage2.

What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I tried with Vue router in App.vue and all is fine. But its not the purpose

```
<template>
  <ion-app>
    <component :is="layout">
      <router-view />
    </component>
  </ion-app>
</template>
```